# WPF TouchPoint size is 0 if there is more than 2 touch points

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

In PreviewTouchMove event when GetTouchPoint is called, Size property changes depending on if hand or finger is used when the system has 2 touch points. But when the system has 4 or 6 touch points this property is always 0. Is it about hardware or driver or a setting?

This code snippet is placed in PreviewTouchMove event.

```
var data = p.GetTouchPoint(null);
if (data.Size.Width > 100 || data.Size.Height > 100)
{
 //change pen into eraser
}
```

This code works fine with 2 touch point system but doesn`t work with 4 or 6 touch point system. How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Its a more likely a driver issue. Size isn't calculated by Windows its calculated by the driver (its listed as an optional, but preferred, information for a touch point in the Windows 7 Touch API which is what WPF in .Net 4 onwards is based on).